# WPF Style Resource not Working

Tags: c#, wpf, resources, styles

All, I want to inherit a generic style for all `DataGrid/ResourceDataGrid`s in my application. To do this I have created a resource file called `ResourceControl.xaml`, in which I have

```
<UserControl x:Class="ResourceStudio.Views.ResourceControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:viewModels="clr-namespace:ResourceStudio.ViewModels" 
             xmlns:dataAccess="clr-namespace:ResourceStudio.DataAccess" 
             xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:ResourceStudio.Controls"
             mc:Ignorable="d">
   <UserControl.Resources>
      <ResourceDictionary>
         <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="MainWindowResources.xaml" />
         </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
      </ResourceDictionary>
   </UserControl.Resources>
   <DockPanel HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
      <TextBox DockPanel.Dock="Top" 
               Name="searchBox" 
               Margin="0,2" 
               VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
               mahAppsControls:TextboxHelper.Watermark="Search Resources" 
               mahAppsControls:TextboxHelper.ClearTextButton="True">
      </TextBox>
      <Grid DockPanel.Dock="Top">
         <controls:ResourceDataGrid x:Name="resourceDataGrid" 
                                    ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Resources}" 
                                    dataAccess:DataGridTextSearch.SearchValue="{Binding ElementName=searchBox, Path=Text, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
                                    dataAccess:DataGridTextSearch.IsAnyTextMatch="False"
                                    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
                                    VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
                                    AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                                    GridLinesVisibility="None"
                                    RowHeaderWidth="0" 
                                    CanUserAddRows="True" 
                                    CanUserDeleteRows="True">
            <controls:ResourceDataGrid.Columns>
               <DataGridTextColumn Header="KeyIndex" Binding="{Binding KeyIndex}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
               <DataGridTextColumn Header="FileName" Binding="{Binding FileName}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
               <DataGridTextColumn Header="ResourceName" Binding="{Binding ResourceName}" IsReadOnly="False"/>
               <controls:CollectionTextColumn Collection="ResourceStringList" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
            </controls:ResourceDataGrid.Columns>
            <controls:ResourceDataGrid.Resources>
               <dataAccess:SearchValueConverter x:Key="searchValueConverter"/>
               <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
                  <Setter Property="dataAccess:DataGridTextSearch.IsTextMatch">
                     <Setter.Value>
                        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource searchValueConverter}">
                           <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}" Path="Content.Text" />
                           <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}" Path="(dataAccess:DataGridTextSearch.SearchValue)" />
                           <Binding ElementName="resourceDataGrid" />
                        </MultiBinding>
                     </Setter.Value>
                  </Setter>
                  <Style.Triggers>
                     <Trigger Property="dataAccess:DataGridTextSearch.IsTextMatch" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Orange" />
                     </Trigger>
                  </Style.Triggers>
               </Style>
            </controls:ResourceDataGrid.Resources>
         </controls:ResourceDataGrid>
      </Grid>
   </DockPanel>
</UserControl>
```

Where in the resource file `MainWindowResources.xaml` I have

```
<!--DataGrid Style-->
<Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGrid}">
   <Setter Property="Background" Value="White"/>
   <Style.Triggers>
      <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
         <!--<Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource AccentColor}"/>-->
         <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
         <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
      </Trigger>
   </Style.Triggers>
</Style>

<!--ResourceDataGrid Style-->
<Style TargetType="{x:Type controls:ResourceDataGrid}">
   <Setter Property="Background" Value="White"/>
   <Style.Triggers>
      <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
         <!--<Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource AccentColor}"/>-->
         <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
         <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
      </Trigger>
   </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

But my `ResourceDataGrid` is not inheriting the style that is defined in the `MainWindowResources.xaml`, why?

Comment: Are MainWindowResources.xaml and ResourceControl is in same folder ? I think there you must set the exact path of your ResourceDictionary.

Comment: Did you check even if your DataGrid is inheriting the style that is defined in the MainWindowResources.xaml ?

Comment: Yes they are in the same directory and it should inherit by default as the resource is defined higher up the visual tree...

Comment: @Killercam: Unfortunately, I can not give an exact answer. To say what the exact problem might be to have to watch the whole project. I tried to simulate your situation with a simple `Label` and I have it working. The only thing, that I can give an example of his, maybe it will help you somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the example of the `Label`.

Listing of `UserControl`:

```
<UserControl x:Class="ResourceDictionaryHelp.ResourceControl"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ResourceDictionaryHelp"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">

<UserControl.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="MainWindowResources.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</UserControl.Resources>

<Grid>
    <Label Content="TestLabel" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />

    <local:MyLabel Content="TestMyLabel" HorizontalAlignment="Right" />
</Grid>

</UserControl>
```

Code behind of `UserControl`:

```
public partial class ResourceControl : UserControl
{
    public ResourceControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}

public class MyLabel : Label 
{
    public MyLabel() 
    {
        base.OnApplyTemplate();
    }   
}
```

Using `UserControl`:

```
<Window x:Class="ResourceDictionaryHelp.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ResourceDictionaryHelp"
    WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

<Grid>
    <local:ResourceControl Width="300" Height="300" />
</Grid>

</Window>
```

`Output`:

[image: BasedOn example]

Listing of `ResourceDictionary`:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ResourceDictionaryHelp">

<Style TargetType="{x:Type Label}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green" />
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="100" />
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="100" />
</Style>

<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:MyLabel}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Pink" />
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="100" />
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="100" />
</Style>

</ResourceDictionary>
```

In this case, inheritance `Style` can be made as follows:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:MyLabel}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Label}}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Pink" />
</Style>
```

It will be the same as:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:MyLabel}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Pink" />
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="100" />
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="100" />
</Style>
```

Also, inheritance can be done by key:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:MyLabel}" BasedOn="{StaticResource MyStyle}">
```

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/{YourAssemblyWhereResourceDictionaryIsLocated};component/Resources/MainWindowResources.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

`component/Resources/MainWindowResources.xaml` is the exact location of your Style Sheet