# How to Stop MahApps.Metro Overriding Styles for Basic Controls

Tags: c#, wpf, mahapps.metro

All, I have started using MahApps.Metro but some controls that this library overrides (`GroupBox` for example) are, to me, a little too rambunctious.

My question is sinple: **if I want to stop MahApps.Metro overriding the style of a certain control, what can I do?**

I have attempted to fix this for a `DataGrid` by overriding the `DataGrid` creating my own `public class SomeDataGrid : DataGrid` and this allows me to use this control as WPF default. However, to do this for ALL the controls is non-ideal.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For the control, which you do not want to overwrite the style, set style `null`:

```
<ProgressBar Style="{x:Null}" Width="300" Height="30" IsIndeterminate="True" />
```

This construction set the `Style` for the control's default value.

Comment: Could you have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/q/17898108/626442? I can't get resources to work with my controls...

Comment: @Killercam: Okay, I'll see it.